# Detect outer edges of complete CGPath

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cgpath

I have a list of `CGPoint`s that are connected using `CGPathAddLineToPoint` going from each consecutive point and then the last point is linked to the first point. Thus I have a complete shape. And I want to detect which points belong to the outermost edge of the connected path so that I can remove any loops from the shape. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578760/how-to-simplify-a-single-complex-uibezierpath-polygon-in-ios/23621812#23621812) answer your question?

Comment: I think it does! Thanks!